# PHP: imagecreatefromjpeg($url) doesn't work if $url contains spaces?

Tags: php

I use a script to get an image from another server and store it in the db, the problem is that when the url has a space in it, the function grabs nothing.

I tried to encode the url and  to simply replace all spaces with %20 but with no success.

I'm running out of options, if any of you could give me some ideas would be great!

Thanks!

```
$thumb=imagecreatefromjpeg(http://www.dummysite.ca/imageone.jpg); //->WORKS
$thumb=imagecreatefromjpeg(http://www.dummysite.ca/image one.jpg); //->DOESN'T WORK
```

EDIT: more info: I'm running a CentOS machine, php 5.2.17

**EDIT: found the answer, replacing spaces with %20 actually WORKS but I was foolish and only replace it before the `imagecreatefromjpeg` call, it turns out `getimagesize` needs it as well**

Comment: Do you have those URLs wrapped with string delimiters?

Comment: Or replace the space with %20

Comment: tried that already, I get a different result (black image instead of error), but still doesn't work. I'm %100 sure the image is on the server

Comment: I believe this is one of those rare times when it's proper to post and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So for those who will have a similar problem

**replacing spaces with `%20` actually WORKS but I was foolish and only replace it before the `imagecreatefromjpeg` call, it turns out `getimagesize` needs it as well**

Answer (score 1):

I would do everything in my power to keep spaces out of filenames. At whatever point the file enters your server it should be renamed to something with underscores. Personally For file uploads I rename every file to a combination of timestamp and the uploader's ip address. Grabbing from another server could use the same logic. If you need to save the original filename just save it as a text string associated with the DB entry.